# SQL 2008 cannot connect with app

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008, windows-phone-7, window

I am attempting to write a C# app that will attach to the 2008 SQL Server I have installed on my PC, but I am missing something, I think with the SQL Configuration.

I am able to connect to the SQL Server in MS-SMS, using both authentication modes.

The SQL Server is named HP_Deskyop\LPR_Home & is running on port 51650.
I have verified that TCP/IP & Named Pipes are enabled for this server.
I am running Norton 360, but I have disabled Smart Firewall.

I am receiving the error below when the Open() line is executed.

```
conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnString);
var cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);
cmd.Connection.Open();
```

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

The connection string is

> Data Source=LPR_HOME;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User
>   ID=sa;Password=XXXXXXX;

I have attempted numerous variations of the connection string, with no luck

HELP!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Connection String to:

```
Data Source=HP_Desktop\LPR_HOME;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=sa;Password=XXXXXXX;
```

This did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but there might be limitations in talking like this over the network with windows phone 7. While Windows phone 7 can use the SQL Compact edition, I don't think it can talk to other SQL servers without going through an intermediate API? What would the app do if you weren't on your home network?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your firewall is blocking the ports that allow connections to SQL Server; The following post from MSDN has a fairly comprehensive set of information as to the port numbers and the respective purpose:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx